# Expected number of Edges required to make a graph connected if the vertices are joined randomly?

Tags: algorithm, math, random, graph-theory

We select two vertices randomly and connect them.
So what is the expected number of edges in the graph when it becomes connected ?

I tried solving it using induction but couldn't reach to an answer.
What will be the right approach to this problem ?

Comment: give the algorithm, this is a bit vague.

Comment: I guess it's something like :
   G = empty
   add n points in G (n>1)
   while G is not connected
      pick random point n1
      pick random point n2 != n1
      add edge n1-n2 in G
   print number of edges in G
(arg, I do not know how to format comments properly)

Comment: When we select two vertices randomly can we pick previously selected vertices once again?

Comment: @IgorKorkhov You can't pick the same pair of vertices

Comment: @UmNyobe I am trying to figure out the algorithm, that's why I posted this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143548/interviewstreet-puzzle-how-many-edges-needed-for-a-random-graph-to-become-conne

Comment: This is an even better paper I found http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1959-11.pdf

Answer (score 1):

For given number of vertices *n* and chosen count of edges, you get the probability of the graphs connectedness as the proportion of connected graphs to all graphs.

Number of all graphs is the combination number of *m* over *n* * (*n* - 1).

Asymptotic formula for number of connected graphs is given in [The asymptotic number of labeled connected graphs with a given number of vertices and edges](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/rsa.3240010202/abstract) by Edward A. Bender,
E. Rodney Canfield, Brendan D. McKay (don't ask me to explain it :-) )

Last, you have to specify what you mean by "expected number" - you have to choose a probability threshold (like 95%) and search for an *m* where this formula gives a probability higher than this threshold.

Comment: This would be a better place to find the paper http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ebender/reprints/97.pdf