# Hackerrank puzzle. How many edges needed for a random graph to become connected

Tags: algorithm, graph

This is Interviewstreet puzzle:

> We have a country containing N cities. Each day we choose 2 cities such that there is no road between them and build a road between them. We choose each pair of nonadjacent cities with equal probability. Let X be the number of days before we obtain a connected country. What is the expected value of X? Output the integer part of answer.

What they are really asking is what number of edges m is needed (on average) for a random graph G(n, m) to become connected.

After writing a program that actually performed the experiment, I came up with this 'solution' that passes 9/10 tests

```
$f = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$n = intval(fgets($f));
echo round(1.25 * $n * log($n, 10));
```

So can it be solved with a single formula? What is the right way of finding likelihood of connectedness of random graph?

Comment: how should I interpret this: "we choose 2 cities such that there is no road between them"? Let's say that there is a road between A-B, and B-C, is it possible for the algorithm to choose a road A-C??

Comment: Yes, if there are only 3 cities (A, B and C), the only remaining pair without a road is A-C. But the country will be already connected with just 2 roads.

Comment: That's a special case: if there are only three cities, no one road will result in a connected country, but any two roads will. For four cities, the chance that the third road connects the country is 80%, and otherwise the fourth road always will, so the estimated number of days is 3.2 (to be truncated to 3). Is that a correct interpretation of the question?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure anymore. What does nonadjacent mean in this context? Is it meant as "cities that don't have a road between them"? Because that's not what the word usually means. The question also doesn't address how a road can be built between A and C, if A is completely surrounded by B. If that's not possible -- it physically isn't -- then the answer doesn't depend solely on N.

Comment: @hvd, you first interpretation is absolutely correct.

Comment: A and B are nonadjacent when there is no road (A, B)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093807/expected-number-of-edges-required-to-make-a-graph-connected-if-the-vertices-are

Comment: +1 for the excellent approximation!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should check out the classic paper of Erdos and Renyi from 1960 entitled ["On the evolution of random graphs"](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1960-10.pdf). It contains complete probabilistic bounds for number of components, size of the largest components, etc.

Here's a bit of the math set-up to get you started.

Let `G(n,m)` be the simple random graph on `n` vertices with `m` edges. Let `X_k` be the number of edges added while there are `k` connected components until there are `k-1` connected components. For example, initially there are `n` connected components, so adding the first edge results in `n-1` connected components so `X_n = 1`. Similarly, the second edge also removes a component (though this happens in one of two ways) so `X_n-1 = 1` as well. Define

```
X = X_n + X_n-1 + ... + X_2
```

The goal is to compute `E(X)`, the expected value of `X`. By additivity, we have

```
E(X) = E(X_n) + E(X_n-1) + ... + E(X_2)
```

It's not too hard to show that the probability that an edge added while there are `k` components reduces the number of components has a lower bound of `(k-1)/(n-1)`. Since `X_k` is the random variable with probability of success given by this amount, the lower bound gives an upper bound for the expectation of `X_k`:

```
E(X_k) <= (n-1)/(k-1)
```

Combining this, we get an asymptotic upper bound for `E(X)` by `n log n`.

With a bit more work and some hints from the Erdos-Renyi paper, you can probably deduce an exact formula.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "initially there are n connected components".  Isn't the whole point that we don't know how many vertices are connected.  How does adding an edge result in fewer connected components.  Am I confusing what you mean by connected components.  I assume it means connected vertices.

Answer (score 1):

OP's is a great solution and with a slight modification to the formula, it will always pass.

```
$f = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');   
$n = intval(fgets($f));  
echo round(1.249 * $n * log($n, 10));// constant factor is changed
```